# Can we get user current location when app is not running in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, geolocation, location

We would like to track user so we want user current location when app is not running also.

We are tracking user when app is in **background or foreground** mode but in some cases like battery drain, memory footprint issue etc, app going to auto kill so in that case we can not track user. We have used **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges** also but in this case we are getting user location once user moved around 500 meter or more from their current location. If user not move after app kill, we can not track. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Wanted precise location tracking, plus the term “kill mode” (it’s not called that) makes this question sound super creepy lol

Answer (score 2):

Certain types of apps, like turn-by-turn navigation apps, are allowed to run from the background, and can continue to monitor the user's location.

Normal apps cannot. If the system terminates your app you stop receiving location updates. As you say, you can use startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges or geofencing to get updates when the device moves a significant distance, but I don't think there is another solution for an app store app.

("Kill mode" isn't really a meaningful term.)